# Self stopping tail operation

Tags: linux, bash, copy-paste, tail

I needed some help for following:

In a menu a tail operation will be carried out and then after a certain output the tail will get terminated and we will get back to the menu.

```
tail -f server.log |
  grep "Started successfully with " &&
  echo "it is working" ||
  echo "not working"
```

Can anyone help me to have a self-closing tail command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@anubhava's answer works, but there is no need for `awk`:

The key is to use `grep` with `-m1`, which makes it return once a match is found, at which point the `tail` process can be killed:

```
tail -f server.log | 
  { grep -m1 "Started successfully with " && pkill -P $$ -x tail; }
```

- `-P $$` (considers only child processes of the current shell) and `-x` (matches process name exactly) ensure that only the `tail` process of interest is killed.
- You could also use a subshell `(...)` instead of command grouping `{ ...; }` (slightly less efficient).
- If the string is *not* found, `grep` only returns in the event that `tail` is *externally* killed - to report this case, add a `||` clause; e.g., `|| echo 'ERROR: tail -f was killed' >&2`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
tail -f server.log | awk '/Started successfully with/{print "it is working"; system("pkill tail"); exit}'
```

There is no case of printing `"not working"` since you're using `tail -f` and you never know for how long your search string isn't there.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for instant reply but the log is not stopping itself and I have to press CTRL+C each time.

Comment: If your server log outputs this line `Started successfully with` this awk will definitely work.

Comment: @anubhava: I think he means for you to add `system("pkill tail")` before your `exit;`

Comment: Thanks I added it in my answer but it worked without it also on my OSX

Comment: Oh, I see - presumably from a broken pipe, maybe?

Comment: Yes I believe due to that only.